# Using Salesforce Data entry when field values have changed

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I am using the Contact object as my "Salesforce Data" entry point, selecting both `IS NEW` and `IS Updated` I would like both scenarios to go into my Journey.

I would like however only selected field updates to be recognised, i.e. when the `FirsName`, or `BirthDate` has changed.

Currently the only options are if the field equals a value or is null (see below)

[image]

What would be the best way to achieve this? Ideally I would like to avoid creating an additional "journey entry" Object in Service Cloud due to limited storage space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Salesforce Data entry event doesn't support on 'IsChanged' function.

As a work around, you can create a Boolean field let's say 'Update SFMC Entry'. You can use [process builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_overview.htm) to add the logic IF Fistname or Birthdate has changed by using [IS Changed](https://www.marksgroup.net/blog/salesforce-com-process-builder-functions-isnew-ischanged/) function you can update the formula field set it as 'True'.

Post some time like 10 mins in the same process builder set the value as 'False' using the timer function. So that the salesforce entry event will recognise when next event happens.

If you update just the record with the same value as True for the next time as well then salesforce entry event won't recognise.

This is the reason am preferring process builder over formula field in salesforce.

Post this you can use the Boolean field in the criteria.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Great answer. I suggest using Flows since Workflows are outdated. Also, in order not to have to change the Boolean value back, I may be suggest simply having a counter of number and changes and using that as a criteria.