# MC Journey Builder not working as expected when using Salesforce data and formula field as an entry

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I'm trying to set up a simple journey for a client to trigger an email once a date is updated in SF. The goal is to schedule a journey which will send an email to the customer once a month with an update. There is a field on the Account object which will show the invoice due date then we have a custom object with different field. That field is showing the invoice due date from the Account object but it's adding 5 days on top using formula.

I'm using the formula field as an entry to inject the customers in the journey but it doesn't work at all. When I update the field with a date from empty or from one date to another I'm expecting the contact to enter the journey but it doesn't work.

Here are the setting I'm using for the entry:

> WHO: Contact ID (Contact) OBJECT: LoyaltyProgramMember (this is the
> custom SF object which was synced in Contact Builder) ACTION: Updated.
> CRITERIA: LoyaltyProgramMember:ContactId WASSET AND
> LoyaltyProgramMember:Next_Loyalty_Statement_Date__c WASSET Journey
> settings: Entry any-time

I wasn't sure if the set up doesn't work because it's a formula field so I tried to test the same set up but using the date field from the Account object but it didn't work.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something here as I've been using this simple set up to trigger a journey when a field is updated.

Thank you

Comment: Formula fields don’t work well with Marketing Cloud Connect (updates to formula fields are not visible in SFMC unless there’s another event that triggers a refresh on the record). I am not sure why the date field didn’t work - do you see “Contact Attempted” at all in Journey History?

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj no I don't see any and I tried different scenarios but nothing worked unfortunately. As you said maybe SFMC doesn't like the formula fields. Here is something I found on similar topic so I was wondering if this could work.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306196/using-salesforce-data-entry-when-field-values-have-changed

Comment: Nikolay, you are not alone we were working through a Journey trying to pull in from the oppty contact role object for several sprints working with SF support as to why the Journey wasn't firing.  In the end they said "DO NOT use lookup fields in your CRITERIA or RELATED OBJECTS CRITERIA.  We've had a Boolean use case work so your work around makes sense.  Thank you for sharing @zuzannmj as we'll add Formula Fields to the list as well in our JB designs.  Thank you both for sharing.

Comment: Thank you @TimZ I also find this article which explaining why Records are not injected to Journey Builder from Sales Cloud. I hope this could be useful https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000316536&type=1

Comment: I think we will go with Automation instead but I can post an update later on.

Comment: Thank you @NikolayNikolov will definitely document this article, we've encountered the state of qualifying issue when testing but it's great to actually read it in black and white.  Also interesting that Formula fields work when created but not updated.

We've found the Related Objects criteria to be the same across the board no matter which field in that they only work when created, not updated.  That said maybe our use case had a formula field...thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

The field type of Sales Cloud fields included in the 'Criteria' can impact if injection will be successful. Formula field types will not trigger based on an 'Update'. Since formula types are dependent on other fields, they are unable to satisfy the state change of 'not qualifying', to 'qualifying'. This state change is required in order to qualify as an 'Update' action. Formula field types will trigger injection when 'Create' is the action used.